Example of undecidable recursive set of formulas in Propositional Logic
Context
In first order logic, we study a lot various undecidable theories like Robinson arithmetic or Peano arithmetic. I was wondering what is there to study in the field of (un)decidability in the context of the propositional logic. I have not found much about it in some introductory texts about undecidability, the focus was always on first-order logic. My question would be the following.
Question
What would be an example of a set $T$ of formulas in propositional logic that is undecidable but recursive? By undecidable I mean that the set of all formulas provable from $T$ is non-recursive.

Let $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ be a recursive function with nonrecursive range. For each $n\in\mathbb N$ let $\varphi_n$ be the $n$-fold conjunction $p_{f(n)}\land\dots\land p_{f(n)}$. The set $T=\{\varphi_n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ is decidable but the set of all formulas provable from $T$ is undecidable.
Alternatively, let $T=\{p_{2n}\land p_{2f(n)+1}:n\in\mathbb N\}$ or let $T=\{(p_n\lor\neg p_n)\land p_{f(n)}:n\in\mathbb N\}$.
